Dockerfile CMD extending image
Context

I want to extend a Dockerfile to install something that runs in the background.
I can't use docker-compose since I'm deploying on fly.io and they don't support it.
I don't want the overhead of something like Supervisord since I'm trying to run on a VM with minimal RAM.

Question
The ghostfolio/ghostfolio Dockerfile ends with
CMD [ "/ghostfolio/entrypoint.sh" ]

I want to extend this base image and run Redis, something like:
FROM ghostfolio/ghostfolio:latest

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-suggests redis-server && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
USER node

CMD redis-server --requirepass "$REDIS_PASSWORD" & ???

I could manually copy /ghostfolio/entrypoint.sh from the base image but then my deployment might break if the upstream image changes.
How can I run redis-server in the background and use the CMD from the base image for the foreground?

From the [tag:docker] tag wiki: DOCKER QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT.

RUN redis-server & ..  CMD [x]

@KenWhite I read that before I posted the question! In your mind, how is asking about the syntax to a command in a scripting language not “related to software development”?

Your question is about docker configuration, not software development.

I disagree. It relates to expressing a specific command in a specific DSL, related to foreground / background tasks, encapsulation, and reusability while writing a customized modification under specific constraints, all of which are software concerns. I could ask a nearly identical question about bash.

A container only runs a single process.  Running multiple containers to run multiple processes is usually the preferred approach; if you really can't then using something like supervisord is usually the second choice.  You can't set a second CMD (only that new command will run and not the first one) and you can't RUN a background process (it gets terminated at the end of the step).

Thanks. I just ended up doing CMD redis-server --requirepass "$REDIS_PASSWORD" & /ghostfolio/entrypoint.sh; hopefully it doesn't break :)
